induced module of hyperoctahedral group
Let $H$ be the subgroup of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$. Let $W_n$ be the group algebra of the hyperoctahedral group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \wr \mathfrak{S}_n$.The induced module $M:=\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \wr H}^{W_n}k$ is defined by $k \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \wr H}W_n$, where $k$ is the trivial module of $H$.
I would like to understand how we can write the $W_n$-mdoule $M$ in terms of $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{\mathfrak{S}_n} k$ and some module of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $k$ is the trivial module of $H$.

The action of the normal subgroup on the induced module $M$ is trivial, and $M$ is just the inflation of $\mathop{\rm Ind}_{H}^{{\mathfrak S}_n}k$.
